# Added a new series on Highcharts/Highstocks with Php/SQL

Tags: php, sql, highcharts

Good morning everyone!
So now I have a year-end project to realize and my client wants to have a website with a graphic. I then used one of the Highcharts graphics. In my database, named "didatec" and for table "acquisition" I have my columns "time","degrees" and "decibels". I started by making my graph with date (on the abscissa) and temperature (in ordinate) and everything works fine!
Now, when I add in my file "values. php" `. $row[' decibel'].` In my file " data. js ", there the graph puts my recovered data but in any direction while my decibels must also be ordered (like temperature).

On this image, the graph works with just the temperature and date. All we need now is decibels...

The graph with just the temperature and date
[image: The graph with just the temperature and date]

Database
[image: Database]

[First part of the data. js file with decibels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHbDQ.png)

[Second part of the data. js file with decibels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPwQa.png)

Graph with data any way (add decibels)
[image: Graph with data any way (add decibels)]

Data retrieved in php on the "values. php"page. First the date and time (timestamp), second the degrees, after decibels
[image: Data retrieved in php on the "values. php"page. First the date and time (timestamp), second the degrees, after decibels]

[The code for "values. php"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEya7.png)

I allow myself to relaunch this subject which is exactly the same but with a refresh of the data live on the graph. I tested the setInterval but it completely refreshes the graph and makes it disappear. I also saw that there was the chart.redraw and the setdata. If you've got a solution, I'm a big hit! Thank you ! :)

Comment: Should post code as text properly formatted, not as images that have to be opened and are hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem how you parse your data. For example:

```
> var data = '2018-02-06 00:00:00/15/15/2018-02-07 00:00:00/12/3'.split('/'); 
> ["2018-02-06 00:00:00", "15", "15", "2018-02-07 00:00:00", "12", "3"]
```

Now you should loop over points like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 3) {
  time.push(data[i]);
  degres.push(parseFloat(data[i + 1]));
  decibels.push(parseFloat(data[i + 2]));
}
```

Of course, if you decide to add more datasets, change `i+=3` to `i+=4` etc.

Comment: It works and I thank you very much! Thank you for the small explanation which is of great help to me :)